# why if condation not update the component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I did that code, but the table doesn't work according to the conditions.

```js
mobilScreen: boolean = false;
pcScreen: boolean = false;


get mobilScreen() {
  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)").matches) {
    return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}


get pcScreen() {
  if ((this.mobilScreen)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

}
```

I tried using `forceUpdate()` but it didn't work.

Comment: are you expecting matchMedia to be reactive on resizing the browser?

Comment: The getters seem ok (although you can also just `return window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)").matches` and `return !this.mobilScreen`). What does the component look like?